# mysql insert record into dynamic table with current date as table name

Tags: mysql

I am running syslog-ng server in Ubuntu. When it receives logs from the local routers/devices, it insert records in LOGS DB How can I automate things so that mysql should create tables according to the current date and insert record into it.

Example if today is 9-11-2018, it should dynamically create table in this DB with  9-11-2018 name and insert record in this table, when date changes, it should auto create 10-11-2018 and insert records in it.

or like year > month > date Is this possible ?

Comment: Just curious why you want a separate table created for each day?

Comment: In most cases runtime DDL means design error. *How can I automate things so that mysql should create tables according to the current date and insert record into it.* Stored procedure with dynamic SQL (prepared statement).

Answer (score 0):

There is rarely a valid reason to build multiple tables with the same schema.

If your goal is to have time-oriented data *and* you intend to purge data after some date, then a `PARTITIONed` table is probably the way to go.  I recommend no more than 50 partitions, so you may want weekly instead of daily partitions.

More on such Partitioning is [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)